Flutter WebView shows white screen on iOS
I want to use the WebView in Flutter to load a code redemption page from apple, so that my user can use discounts on subscriptions. For example pages like Google, Flutter.dev, ... it works fine, but using the url from apple sadly won't. I just get a blank white screen in my body - the appbar works fine. What could be wrong?
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import '../../configuration/theme.dart';


class FumiProPromoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  String code;
  //Variable Code übergeben
  FumiProPromoPage({
    Key? key,
    required this.code,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FumiProPromoPage> createState() => _FumiProPromoPageState();
}

class _FumiProPromoPageState extends State<FumiProPromoPage> {
  var loadingPercentage = 0;
  late WebViewController controller;
  final GlobalKey webViewKey = GlobalKey();

  String promourl = "https://google.de";
  String url = "";
  double progress = 0;
  final urlController = TextEditingController();


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    promourl = 'https://apps.apple.com/redeem?ctx=offercodes&id=xxxxxxxx&code=${widget.code}';
    print(promourl);

    controller = WebViewController()
    ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
    ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
    ..setNavigationDelegate(
      NavigationDelegate(
        onProgress: (int progress) {
          // Update loading bar.
        },
        onPageStarted: (String url) {},
        onPageFinished: (String url) {},
        onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {},
        onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
          if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
            return NavigationDecision.prevent;
          }
          return NavigationDecision.navigate;
        },
      ),
    )
    ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(promourl));
  }
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
            elevation: 0,
            backgroundColor: fumigruenAccent,
            title: const Text(
              "Promocode einlösen",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
            leading: CloseButton(
              color: Colors.black,
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),),
        
        
      body: 
      
      Stack(
        children: [
          WebViewWidget(
            controller: controller,
          ), 
          
          loadingPercentage < 100
              ? LinearProgressIndicator(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  value: loadingPercentage / 100.0,
                )
              : Container()
        ],
      ), 
    );
  }
}

I also deactivated the Apple Transport Security (ATS) feature for http requests to figure out if that's the problem. It sadly didn't work.
To do this I added the following lines to my Info.plist
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
</dict>

Any ideas? many thanks in advance!

I faced the same issue. The problem I found is that when using the useShouldOverrideUrlLoading attribute, you need to define the shouldOverrideUrlLoading function.
shouldOverrideUrlLoading: (controller, action) async {
  return NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW;
},

If you use the useShouldOverrideUrlLoading attribute, you must define this method.
